# Проверка содержимого массива на тип данных js

Tags: javascript, массивы, типы-данных

Вопрос к знатокам: как сделать проверку на тип данных в массиве, чтобы эта проверка не проверяла тип данных самих переменных массива?
То есть, есть у меня массив:

```
let BB = 'ccc';
let arr = ['aaa','ggg', BB,'']
```

А есть у меня функция, которая пробегается по массиву и выполняет некоторые действия, в зависимости от типа данных элементов массива. В конкретном данном случае, привязка идет к строке:

```
function change() {
        let a = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i] == '' || typeof arr[i] != 'string') {
            a[i] = arr[i]
          } else {
            a[i] = getSummary(arr[i]) // здесь производятся некоторые вычисления в зависимости от того, какая строка содержалась в массиве.
          }
        }
        return a;
      }

console.log(a); 
// итоговый массив получается вот такой: true, true, undefined, ''
// а нужно чтобы получилось: true, true, 'ccc', ''
```

И все бы хорошо, но мне нужно, чтобы когда алгоритм натыкался на `ВВ`, он в итоговый массив записывал `'ccc'` вместо себя, однако он проверяя массив на тип данных, так же проверяет `ВВ` и выяснив, что тот тоже содержит строку, пытается применить к нему `getSummary(arr[i])`, но так как под эту строку нет прописанных действий, естественно, что результат выпадает в ошибку.

Итак, повторю свой вопрос, как мне проверить массив на тип данных, при этом не проверяя типа данных переменных, которые в нем содержаться? То есть должно получится, если строка, то выполняем указанное действие, если что-то другое (например, переменная типа строка), то игнорируем это. Методы `isNaN()` и `typeof` не помогли, так как они все равно заглядывают в тип данных переменной.

Comment: Ты хочешь невозможного. В массиве нет никаких переменных.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, немного подправил свой вопрос, чтобы было понятно, что я пытаюсь сделать.

Comment: Без разницы. В твоём массиве нет переменных. В нём четыре строчки и всё.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, BB - это переменная, в которой храниться строка...

Comment: Без разницы. Массивы `['aaa', 'ggg', BB, '']` и `['aaa', 'ggg', 'ccc', '']` для JS абсолютно одинаковы. Нигде не сохраняется информация о происхождении данных, хоть литерал, хоть переменная, хоть вызов функции…

Comment: @Alexey Ten, печально... Придется изобретать какие-нибудь "костыли".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте массив исключений и будет Вам счастье

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
const exeption = ['c', 'd']

const result = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
    exeption.includes(el) ? acc.push(el) : acc.push(getSummary(el))

    return acc
}, [])

function getSummary(item) {
    return true
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно добавить в условие проверку с заданной переменной:

```
let BB = 'ccc';
let arr = ['aaa','ggg', BB,'']

function change() {
        let a = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i] == '' || typeof arr[i] != 'string' || arr[i] == BB) {
            a[i] = arr[i]
          } else {
            a[i] = getSummary(arr[i]) // здесь производятся некоторые вычисления в зависимости от того, какая строка содержалась в массиве.
          }
        }
        return a;
      }

console.log(a); 
// получилось: true, true, 'ccc', ''
```

вот только если таких переменных несколько, то для каждой нужно будет прописывать проверку, что не очень удобно и гибко

========================================

Второй вариант, добавить массив допустимых значений для `getSummary` и каждый раз при вводе нового элемента в функцию, проверять, является он в списке допустимых:

```
let BB = 'ccc';
let arr = ['aaa','ggg', BB,'']
let arr2 = ['aaa','ggg']

function change() {
        let a = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i] == '' || typeof arr[i] != 'string') {
            a[i] = arr[i]
          } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
             if (arr2[j] === arr[i]) {
            a[i] = getSummary(arr[i]) 
          } 
        }
        }
        return a;
      }

console.log(a); 
// получилось: true, true, 'ccc', ''
```

Comment: У вас какая-то неправильная модель данных похоже. Например, если известно что `getSummary` принимает только `'aaa'` и `'ggg'`, то это и нужно проверять. Или возможно функция `getSummary` может сама проверять что пришло и игнорировать неизвестные ей значения.

Comment: Или, если верить вашему примеру с выводом, то может достаточно поменять одну строчку в else: `a[i] = getSummary(arr[i]) ?? arr[i];`

Comment: @Alexey Ten, проблема в том, что данных может быть слишком много, чтобы проводить проверку по каждой из них, поэтому я и решил зацепиться за тип данных, так как он один у всех входящих в `getSummary` данных, но мне нужно как-то отделить от общего массива данных текстовые данные, которые не предназначены для использования в `getSummary`. На примере с 4 элементами, это кажется просто глупым, но когда данных несколько сотен, то актуальность вопроса резко возростает.